# Parse json with newline

Tags: json, crystal-lang

Given a Json like this:

```
{
  "description": "foo \n bar"
}
```

If I try to create a `Hash(String, String)` using method `from_json` I get the following error:

```
Unexpected char '
' at 1:22 (JSON::ParseException)
```

How can I correctly parse it?

```
require "json"

Hash(String, String).from_json(%({"description": "foo \n bar"}))
```

https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3ynh

Comment: Yeah! The problem is indeed the \n, the string I want to parse does have it :sweatsmile:

Comment: I think the problem is that creating a JSON using `%()` interprets newline instead of leaving the characters, see this example https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/3ynq

Comment: Sorry, I've deleted my original comment because I just read the title again and felt silly. Maybe you need to escape that character? I tried "\\n" and it worked. But that isn't the best solution.

Comment: Problem was that `%()` interprets newline character, in a real JSON from an API it isn't a problem, thanks Dawid anyways

Comment: Try using `%q(... Your json ...)` this should not interpret the newline